# Why I get this error - Unity library missing for the selected architecture armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I try build android project on Unity. But i have this issues:
[image]

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
 at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer 
 (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bf] in 
 <3d6d6a4a6d7c4ec2aa654b7d8f54a096>:0 
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean 
 askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in 
<3d6d6a4a6d7c4ec2aa654b7d8f54a096>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)

___________________________________________________________
       Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 7 seconds (7119 ms)
     UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
```

---

```
 UnityException: Unable to package apk
 Unity library missing for the selected architecture armeabi-v7a(C:/Editor/2019.4.33f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Releas 
     e\StaticLibs\armeabi-v7a\libunityruntime.a) !
   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I tried all solutions on the same problem from the internet but it doesn't work.
[image: preferences]
[image: build settings]
[image: player settings]

Any ideas?

Comment: If you uncheck `ARMv7` in the player settings does it work? What's in your project as far as plugins? Usually this means that a plugin doesn't provide 32-bit code or one or more of the 32-bit libraries are not set properly in the inspector to be included in the build.

Comment: @RetiredNinja if I uncheck ARMv7 it shows another error:
UnityException: Unable to package apk
Unity library missing for the selected architecture arm64-v8a (C:/Editor/2019.4.33f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\Release\StaticLibs\arm64-v8a\libunityruntime.a) !
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Same question about plugins. It's also possible your Unity installation is incomplete or corrupted.

Comment: @RetiredNinja to be honest I'm new in unity and I do not properly understand the question about plugins..

Comment: Try going to your installations in Unity Hub, and adding modules under the ellipses button on the relevant Unity installation. Try re-installing Android modules. The warnings in your platform settings about missing reccomended JDK and NDK (despite the box being checked to use reccomended installs) should be addressed before attempting to build.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the `Android Build Support` module via Unity Hub fixed this issue for me.